# Replace all files or a select few during react-native upgrade?

Tags: react-native, upgrade

While runnning react-native upgrade, I'm asked if I want to replace several files one by one. Is it best to agree to all? Some of them are files like .gitignore and the app.main. which seem risky to agree to replace:

`Do you want to keep your .gitignore or replace it with the latest version?
If you ever made any changes to this file, you'll probably want to keep it.
You can see the new version here: /Users/$USER/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/templates/HelloWorld/_gitignore
Do you want to replace .gitignore? Answer y to replace, n to keep your version:`

Appreciative of any explanation of this.

Comment: You should use `react-native-git-upgrade` instead, which will attempt to alter those files and make necessary changes and allow you to fix any conflicts introduced. It's much better than just replacing them all

Comment: Thanks Robbie, I will try that.